# HP 15s-dy3501TU backlit keyboard upgrade

Tags: laptop, keyboards

I am using HP **15sdy-3501TU** which originally comes with a non backlit keyboard. I opened its motherboard and found a connector just below the keyboard designated as "**JKBL**" , which can be seen in the picture:[image]

Can somebody confirm if it is the backlight connector of the keyboard or not? if it is not, is there any backlit connector for this specific model laptop's motherboard? if the motherboard supports backlit then can somebody suggest an hp laptop such that whose keyboard can be used in my laptop to upgrade it to a backlit keyboard laptop?